# How can I derive a public key from a known private key?

Tags: javascript, key, programmatically

Edpk from a edsk, programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use [pytezos](https://github.com/baking-bad/pytezos) and namely this [method](https://github.com/baking-bad/pytezos/blob/master/pytezos/crypto.py#L86)

```
@classmethod
def from_key(cls, key, passphrase=''):
    """
    Creates a key object from a base58 encoded key.
    :param key: a public or secret key in base58 encoding
    :param passphrase: the passphrase used if the key provided is an encrypted private key
    """
```

Comment: Actually what I needed exactly was in function "from_secret_key" of the same file in PyTezos. The line below will let me reproduce it in Java:

Comment: public_key = pysodium.crypto_sign_sk_to_pk(sk=secret_key)